# How do I implement GlideApp in a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-glide

I am trying to get a picture from Firebase storage inside a fragment with kotlin but it is just not working.  Here's the code:

```
val data = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
val storageRef = data.getReference()
val pathReference = storageRef.child(user.uid.toString() + "/images/coverphoto/")

GlideApp.with(context)
     .load(pathReference)
     .into(view.profileUserCoverPhoto)
```

This gives me the error:  `Required:  Context   Found:  Context?`

I also tried `GlideApp.with(this@Profile)` and `GlideApp.with(view.context)` (I inflate my view into `view` which is why I tried that.  I cannot figure out what context should be and I believe that is the issue.  The image is uploaded to Firebase just fine so I know it is there.  I believe the error is with my glide code.  Specifically the `context` part of the code but I don't know what I am doing wrong or what I should use.  Any help would be appreciated.

*****Update*****

I just tested Glide with a URL from the web and it works just fine.  I also just tested with the firebase URL to the image "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cyber-chatter.appspot.com/o/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2%2Fimages%2Fcoverphoto?alt=media&token=7876830c-393f-4a00-be61-80fbd775cf28" and that works just fine as well.  I've gone over my pathReference and it is building correctly.

This is confusing and frustrating.  I've been trying to figure out the solution for 3 days now.  I have no clue what I am doing wrong...

Comment: So I just test glide with a url from the web"https://fixcom.azureedge.net/assets/content/19743/craft-beer-header.png" and the picture loads just fine.  So it's not with the context, it is something else and I don't know what...

Comment: Logging the path returns `gs://cyber-chatter.appspot.com/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2/images/coverphoto` which is not the URL, but is correct

Comment: if I use `.pathReference.path` it returns `/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2/images/coverphoto` which is the literal path without the url.

Comment: In firebase you would have created a table for storing imageurls. You will have to get reference to that. Can you show snapshot of that

Comment: So, I moved the code out of `onViewCreated` and out of an `async`call to on `onViewCreate` and now I get the real problem: `Request threw uncaught throwable
                 com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://cyber-chatter.appspot.com/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2/images/coverphoto`.  It's not being able to find the model in the Glide library.  But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The real issue seems to be that the image url is incorrect

Comment: I honestly think it's the Model, not the URL.  Firebase doesn't return a URL in the traditional sense, just a path which is not what `ImageView` wants.  I think the AppGlideModule is wrong, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!  I figured out the issue:

My requiredAppGlideModule.kt was not correct.  It should look like this for kotlin:

```
import android.content.Context
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader
import java.io.InputStream
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder



@GlideModule
class RequiredAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java,
                FirebaseImageLoader.Factory())
    }
}
```

Once I did this and added all correct import references shwon above, I was getting an unknown reference error for `FirebaseImageLoader` so I also created a FirebaseImageLoader.kt class using this code:

```
package com.firebase.ui.storage.images

import android.util.Log    
import com.bumptech.glide.Priority
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Key
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Options
import com.bumptech.glide.load.data.DataFetcher
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoaderFactory
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask

import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.security.MessageDigest

/**
 * ModelLoader implementation to download images from FirebaseStorage with Glide.
 *
 *
 *
 * First, register this class in your AppGlideModule:
 * <pre>
 * @Override
 * public void registerComponents(Context context, Registry registry) {
 * // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
 * registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
 * new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
 * }
</pre> *
 *
 *
 *
 * Then load a StorageReference into an ImageView.
 * <pre>
 * StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("myimage");
 * ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
 *
 * GlideApp.with(this)
 * .load(ref)
 * .into(iv);
</pre> *
 */
class FirebaseImageLoader : ModelLoader<StorageReference, InputStream> {


    /**
     * Factory to create [FirebaseImageLoader].
     */
    class Factory : ModelLoaderFactory<StorageReference, InputStream> {

        override fun build(factory: MultiModelLoaderFactory): ModelLoader<StorageReference, InputStream> {
            return FirebaseImageLoader()
        }

        override fun teardown() {
            // No-op
        }
    }

    override fun buildLoadData(reference: StorageReference,
                               height: Int,
                               width: Int,
                               options: Options): ModelLoader.LoadData<InputStream>? {
        return ModelLoader.LoadData(
                FirebaseStorageKey(reference),
                FirebaseStorageFetcher(reference))
    }

    override fun handles(reference: StorageReference): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    private class FirebaseStorageKey(private val mRef: StorageReference) : Key {

        override fun updateDiskCacheKey(digest: MessageDigest) {
            digest.update(mRef.path.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
        }
    }

    private class FirebaseStorageFetcher(private val mRef: StorageReference) : DataFetcher<InputStream> {
        private var mStreamTask: StreamDownloadTask? = null
        private var mInputStream: InputStream? = null

        override fun loadData(priority: Priority,
                              callback: DataFetcher.DataCallback<in InputStream>) {
            mStreamTask = mRef.stream
            mStreamTask!!
                    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                        mInputStream = snapshot.stream
                        callback.onDataReady(mInputStream)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e -> callback.onLoadFailed(e) }
        }

        override fun cleanup() {
            // Close stream if possible
            if (mInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    mInputStream!!.close()
                    mInputStream = null
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Could not close stream", e)
                }

            }
        }

        override fun cancel() {
            // Cancel task if possible
            if (mStreamTask != null && mStreamTask!!.isInProgress) {
                mStreamTask!!.cancel()
            }
        }

        override fun getDataClass(): Class<InputStream> {
            return InputStream::class.java
        }

        override fun getDataSource(): DataSource {
            return DataSource.REMOTE
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "FirebaseImageLoader"
    }
}
```

I then imported this into my `requiredAppGlideModule.kt` and as soon as I did those two things, the image loaded with no problems at all!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation error:

> Required:  Context   Found:  Context?

Is due to the Fragment.getContext() method being annotated @Nullable. If the fragment is not attached it will return null.

```
context?.let { // If context is not null use it in the passed block as `it`
    GlideApp.with(it)
         .load(pathReference)
         .into(view.profileUserCoverPhoto) 
}
```

See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html or Kotlin In Action 6.1 https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action

Comment: I figured out the Context error.  I can load an image from a web url using the `.load{"www.url-to-image.com/image.jpg")` and it will put that image into the `ImageView` but when I try and load from the database:  `val data = FirebaseStorage.getInstance() val storageRef = data.getReference() val pathReference = storageRef.child(user.uid + "/images/coverphoto/") GlideApp.with(view.context!!) .load(pathReference) .into(view.profileUserCoverPhoto)` I get nothing but white.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, a datatype can be Nullable or Non-Nullable. To mark as nullable we use a question mark. 
This is Non Nullable

```
var c: Context // Equivalent to @NonNullable Context c;
```

This is Nullable

```
var c: Context? // Equivalent to @Nullable Context c;
```

Now, your GlideApp requires a nonnullable context. But, your fragments getContext method can return null. So. lets take a look at that method.

```
  /**
    * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
    *
    * @see #requireContext()
    */
    @Nullable
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }

    @Nullable
    final public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
        return mHost == null ? null : (FragmentActivity) mHost.getActivity();
    }
```

So, you can get null when the fragment is not attached to activity. Basically, you can be sure that the context is not null between Fragment's onAttach and onDetach method.

So between that like in onCreate you can use Non null assertion

```
GlideApp.with(getContext()!!)
```

Otherwise, you can always check for null values as mentioned in above answers.

```
getContext()?.let{ GlideApp.with(it) ... }
```

https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

Comment: It has something to do with the `.load(pathReference)` I believe.  I can use `GlideApp.with(view.context!!)` with `.into(www.urltoimage.com/image.jpg)' and it will load an image from a web url and put it into the `ImageView`.  But when I use:  `val data = FirebaseStorage.getInstance() val storageRef = data.getReference() val pathReference = storageRef.child(user.uid + "/images/coverphoto/") GlideApp.with(view.context!!) .load(pathReference) .into(view.profileUserCoverPhoto)`  I just get white.  Nothing else.

Comment: why don't you print out path reference in log and check if it's the same. is that path reference accessible without authorization, on browser

Comment: Logging the path returns `gs://cyber-chatter.appspot.com/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2/images/coverphoto` which is not the URL, but is correct

Comment: if I use `.pathReference.path` it returns `/8YiLlLOxRgO2FjF9OSUKBeL7ckn2/images/coverphoto which is the literal path without the url.`

Comment: Can you tell me what is stored at user.uid.toString() + "/images/coverphoto/". I am assuming you are mapping that value to a pojo class. Does it contain a url which is accessible directly in browser

Comment: See me answer.  It was the model inside the `requiredAppGlideModule.kt` that was incorrect.  Once I fixed this, everything works perfectly.